# Accessing local files on android from epub files

Tags: android, epub

I am trying to have an epub file link to an html document that is stored locally on my device.
I have an `<a>` tag with the href being:

"file://sdcard/mobi/content/file.html".

This does not work.
The epub file is currently located in the mobi directory as shown above, is there a way to relatively access the html file or is my href wrong?
I have tested the reader and it can open the file.html page if it is hosted on our local network.

Thank you in advance for any help